# Django Form csrf_token

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

whenever we want to perform a `POST` request in django we need to add a `csrf_token`. For example if you want to create a form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
```

This is pretty simple if you do it in `HTML`. However, I want to create forms dynamically using `jQuery`. I have the following code:

```
                   $div = $('<form/>')   // First I am creating the `form` div 
                       .attr("method","POST") //POST method
                       .attr("action","#");
                   ($div).appendTo('#team_notification_'+index); //Appending it 
                   var $button  = $('<button/>') //Creating the buttons
                       .attr("type","submit")
                       .attr("name","Accept")
                       .attr("value", invite[0].pk); //Setting some value
                   $($button).appendTo($div);
```

But how can I append the `csrf_token` using jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/ and check the `getCookie` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var $csrf = $('<input/>') 
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "csrfmiddlewaretoken")
               .attr("value", "{{csrf_token}}");
$($csrf).appendTo($div);
```